# Perl multibyte support

Tags: perl, multibyte

I am facing this problem where due to multibyte characters the string value changes when returned from a function.Please consider below statements

```
print "charEncoding string val = " . $enc->($val) . "\n\n";
#prints charEncoding string val = &#27489;&#36814;&#20358;&#21040;&#38597;&#34382;!

my $encoded = $enc->($val);  <---- $encoded is not same as $enc->($val).

print "\n charEncodingo $encoded == $val " ;
#prints charEncodingo æ­¡è¿&#142;ä¾&#134;å&#136;°é&#155;&#133;è&#153;&#142;! == &#27489;&#36814;&#20358;&#21040;&#38597;&#34382;!
```

Comment: What is `$enc`? What is the difference between `$val` and `$enc->($val)`?

Comment: This is Perl , In case I missed saying that and $enc === Encode::encode_utf8

Comment: Perl doesn’t have multibyte anything.  It has characters.

Comment: don't think so. I am talking about encoding here . please take a look the problem statement.

Comment: I stand by what I said. Perl does not have multibyte anything.  Its strings are composed of abstract characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ... yeah. The purpose of most functions, including `Encode::encode_utf8`, is to change the value of the input. The input to `Encode::encode_utf8` may contain wide characters (where `ord($char) > 255`), but the output is always a **byte string** (where `ord($char) <= 255` is true for every character in the string).

The part of your question that is hard to believe is your first sample output,

```
#prints charEncoding string val = &#27489;&#36814;&#20358; ...
```

where you suggest that the output of `Encode::encode_utf8` contained wide characters. You should double check that part.